# How to create an If Loop

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I have 2 columns with USD amounts of payments I need to compare. Data is from two different sources but they should match. Every month there is different number of payments so I dont know if next time there will be 20 or 30 of them. So I need to compare these 2 columens.  What I want to do is using if function

```
If [n3] = [u3] Then
    [q3] = "yes"
Else
    [q3] = "no"
End If
```

and I dont know how to use loops to do this with every payment.

Comment: look at `for next loop` `find last cell in range vba` or just use a formula in Q?

Comment: google `For Loops vba` and `find last cell with data in column vba`  using that information try to construct the proper loop.  when you get stuck come back with your attempt and explain the errors.

Comment: Note that they're called `loops`, not `cycles`.  And do you actually *want* to do this in VBA,, or would you rather keep it simpler with w a worksheet formula?

Comment: thanks for answers I will check your suggestions. ashleedawg yes it would be easier but Its more complex than just this so I want to inculde it in the whole code. It will be cleaner.

Comment: Alright, what are the constraints? (ie., minimum & maximum row/columns should have this formula on what condition?)

Comment: FYI this `[A1]` notation is horrendous... it's shorthand notation that's useful for quick calls in the *immediate pane* (Ctrl+G), but for actual VBA code that's meant to be *read* and *maintained*, you'll want to learn to use the `Range` class explicitly and properly. `If [n3] = [u3] Then` would be something like `If ActiveSheet.Range("N3").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("U3").Value Then` - and either would cause run-time error 13 ("type mismatch") if N3 or U3 contains an error value (e.g. `#VALUE!` or `#N/A`).

Comment: Couple side notes: It's not good practice to use shortcuts (like `[A1]` instead of a fully qualified range) in production.  They are only intended for testing.  Also, when leaving a comment with someone's name, add an "at" symbol -- that way they'll be notified of the new message, like you were for this: @xyzed  (max 1 person per comment)

Answer (score 0):

1. Function to count the number of rows with values starting from a cell (defined as a `Range` object)

   ```
   Public Function CountRows(ByVal r As Range) As Long
       If IsEmpty(r) Then
           CountRows = 0
       ElseIf IsEmpty(r.Offset(1, 0)) Then
           CountRows = 1
       Else
           CountRows = r.Worksheet.Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
       End If
   End Function
   ```
2. Example Usage inside the Sheet code where you want the check to happen.

   ```
   Public Sub CheckPayments()
       Dim rn as Range, ru as Range, rq as Range
       'One price column & first value
       Set rn = Range("N3")
       'Otjher price column & first value
       Set ru = Range("U3")
       ' Check result column & first value
       Set rq = Range("Q3")

       Dim i as Long, n as Long
       ' Count non-empty cells below "N3"
       n = CountRows(rn)

       'Loop through rows
       For i = 1 to n
           ' Check for matching values
           If rn.Cells(i,1).Value = ru.Cells(i,1).Value Then
               rq.Cells(i,1).Value = "yes"
           Else
               rq.Cells(i,1).Value = "no"
           End If
       Next i
   End Sub
   ```